# How can I create an object whose methods pass on their calls to a promise that will eventually fulfill them?

Tags: javascript, logging, javascript-objects, es6-promise

I have a web application that I want to allow to ship logs to a server. I am using a logging library (Elasticsearch's RUM agent, though that's not relevant here) that is initialised as a singleton like this...

```
// logger.js
const config = {
    logServerUrl: 'https://loggingserver.com',
    appEnvironment: 'production',
}

const logger = initLogger(config)

export default logger
```

and used elsewhere in my web application like this...

```
// error_handling.js
import logger from 'logger'
// ...
logger.startTransaction({id: 1234, name: 'foo'})
logger.logError(someError)
logger.stopTransaction(1234)

// ... and possibly more nested stuff like
logger.metadata.add('user', 'alice')
```

Mainly I just need to call logger methods which have no (or uninteresting) return values.

The problem is, I need to get my config information from an asynchronous `fetch`, but I want the logger to be instantly available to the rest of the application to be used as shown above. Probably I should just export a promise to the logger and use it like
`loggerPromise.then(logger => logger.logError(someError))`, but I was thinking of something like this...

```
// logger.js
const loggerPromise = fetch('/config')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => initLogger(json))

const fakeLogger = {
    logError: error => loggerPromise.then(logger => logger.logError(error)),
    metadata: {
        add: (key, value) => loggerPromise.then(logger => logger.metadata.add(key, value)),
    },
    //... plus all the other methods I want to use in my application, like startTransaction
}

export default fakeLogger
```

so that the rest of the application can use the logger as if it was initialised at module export time rather than after the promise resolution.

My method "works", but there is a lot of boiler plate to "pass through" the method calls to the underlying logger. It means that if the library adds new methods I'll have to implement them too in my fake logger proxy.

I appreciate that this only works if you don't care about return values.

I feel like there must be a way of wrapping a promise in such a way to make it look like the object it will eventually resolve to. Is there some language feature or clever pattern than I am missing? Something like python's `__getattr__` perhaps? Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) to support `await` at the top level, then you could just `await` the configuration and everything is fine.

However until now that is not possible.

Comment: This looks cool! I hadn't heard about this proposal. However, in my case it would block the code that uses the logger and I might not want a logger initialisation failure to prevent the rest of the app working. Food for thought, though.